# How can I make png image act as a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, button

I am using Dreamweaver for the first time to code. I am intermediate in HTML.

I've been trying to use a png file as a button. I've found some sources stating that a ...

```
<button src=Home_button> </button>
```

... will work, but I have tried it, and to no avail, it does not work. Any suggestions?

---

#### NOTE:

I am also using a CSS to build this *Very* basic website.

Comment: have you tried `<input type="image">` (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_image)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add `background-image` to your button.

```
<button id="home_button">click me</button>
```

and then add:

```
#home_button {
  background-image: url(...);
}
```

You may need to add further styling to it of course, such as widths and other background properties to get it just right. But this is how you add a background image to a button.

Here's a working demo as well:

```css
#home_button {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfed8.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #eee;
  }
```

```html
<button id="home_button"></button>
```

Comment: I would prefer this instead of the plain HTML solution that simply wraps the `<img>` tag inside `<a>` tags. In case you ever want the picture to change in example; when hovering the button, you can achieve it by modifying the `background-image` property in CSS.

Comment: @ProDexorite, agreed. There's alot of flexibility as well with all the `background` properties that you can't get as easily with the regular `img`.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks guys! Therefore to link it, I'd use a "href="?

Comment: So a 'href=' would do the job to link it to the .png? Sorry

Comment: You want it to use the image as the background to the button, but also link to the background when the user presses the button?

Comment: Yes, to link it to another HTML page, I am making a basic multi-page website.

Comment: Okay, well there are many ways to do this. If you want to use a `button` specifically, then you can add `onclick="location.href='http://google.com';"` to the button. Another option is to wrap an `img` tag inside of an `a` tag and style the `a` to look like a button. Alternatively, wrap your button inside an `a` tag that links to your page.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `img` tag inside your `button` tag.

```html
<button id="bar" type="submit"><img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a" /></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to create something that looks like an image and behaves like a button.

Here-below are code examples demonstrating 5 options worth considering...

---

#### Option 1 :

You could put an `<img>` element inside a `<button>` element :

```js
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert('Button clicked');
});
```

```css
button, img {
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="myButton">
    <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/bf4cc94221382810233575862875e687?s=150" alt="">
</button>
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/d53pq54s/7/))

---

#### Option 2 :

You could use an `<a>`-tag instead :

```js
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert('Button clicked');
});
```

```css
a {
    border: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<a id="myButton" href="#">
    <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/bf4cc94221382810233575862875e687?s=150" alt="">
</a>
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/d53pq54s/5/))

---

#### Option 3 :

You could just attach your click handler directly to your image :

```js
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert('Button clicked');
});
```

```html
<img id="myButton" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/bf4cc94221382810233575862875e687?s=150" alt="">
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/d53pq54s/4/))

---

#### Option 4 :

You could set your image as a background-image of a `<button>`-tag or other tag that represents a button.

```js
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert('Button clicked');
});
```

```css
input[type=submit] {
    background: url("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/bf4cc94221382810233575862875e687?s=150");
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" id="myButton">
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/d53pq54s/10/))

---

#### Option 5 :

You could set your image as a background-image of an `<a>`-tag, a `<div>`-tag or another tag that doesn't represent a button :

```js
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert('Button clicked');
});
```

```css
div {
    background: url("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/bf4cc94221382810233575862875e687?s=150");
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="myButton"></div>
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/d53pq54s/11/))

Answer (score 0):

You could do `<a href="#"><img src="#" alt="" /></a>` to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to use an image as a button..

```
    <a href="your_link.html">
      <img id="mypic' src="path_to_your.png" alt="MyImage" width="200" height="300" />
    </a>
css..
#mypic {
    background: #390239;
    color:#7e4a00;
    border:#7e4a00 2px solid;
    border-color:;
    outline:none;
    padding: 6px;
    border-radius:5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Chris also has a good answer... it depends on what looks good on the page, as well as your coding knowledge.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what you can do...

**HTML**

```
<button>Click Me</button>
```

**CSS**

```
button {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px // height of your button image
  text-indent: -9999px // hide if you have text inside <button>
  width: 100px // width of your button image
}
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: And where exactly is the image that should be used in this button? This does not really answer the question at all.

Comment: Oops sorry, forgot to add background: url(image.png); :)