# Contour button to outline of image

Tags: html, css, image, button, bootstrap-4

**Please note: I have already tried the solution listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35838565/how-can-i-make-png-image-act-as-a-button) which does not serve my purposes as it still draws a box around the image**

**Update: I have taken a further look into this and found that one solution is to draw an SVG of the image in question and make this the button so that there is not such a large box surrounding the image. I would prefer not to do this as I have many assets but would this be the only solution?**

I am trying to place a button on my website but make it so that the clickable area is exactly the image and nothing else. I have been trying to find solutions for this but perhaps I am not searching the correct terms.

At present, I am using Bootstrap to create a button for a carousel. This works fine but the issue I am having is the [square border around the button itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XObYu.jpg) which will cause a problem as I put more buttons on the page that are closely placed together.

I would like the clickable area to be restricted strictly to the png itself, which includes the white border seen on the image linked above.

My code at present looks as follows.

HTML:

```
    <div class='background'></div>
      <div class="map">
        <img id='mainMap' src='assets/maps/map.png' alt='map'>
        <!-- Modal's toggle button has data that's used to determine what content to use -->

        <!-- Bridge icons -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary-outline-btn bridge-btn" id='bridge1' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"><img class="bridge_icon" src="assets/icons/bridge1.png" alt="image"></button>
      </div>
```

CSS:

```
.camera_icon, .video_icon{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.bridge_icon {
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#bridge1 {
  top: 3%;
  left: 10%;
  position: inherit;
}

/* Buttons */

.btn, .btn-outline-primary, .video-btn {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: #ccc;
  padding: 0px;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.btn:focus,.btn:active {
   outline: none !important;
   box-shadow: none;
}

.bridge-btn {
  border-color: hotpink;
}

.btn-outline-primary:hover, .video-btn:hover{
  background-color: #e4dbef;
  border-color: #ccc;
}

.btn-outline-primary:focus, .video-btn:focus{
  background-color: #e4dbef;
  outline: none;
  border-color: #ccc;
}

.btn:focus, .btn:active:focus, .btn.active:focus { outline: none; ! important; outline-style: none; }
```

Any help you could provide would be very useful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the button has a border you don't want? If that is the case try changing btn-primary-outline-btn to btn-transparent-outline-btn

Comment: Hi @Kevin tierney. It is more like it creates a box much larger than the image itself. The image itself is the button but an irregular shape (as per the image linked in OP). So when multiple images are in close proximity, a click may select the wrong button. Does ```btn-transparent-outline-btn``` resolve this?